# Ubuntu ISO with make and gcc

Tags: wireless, compiling, iso, gcc, make

Are there any ubuntu ISO's that you can boot with that already have make and/or gcc (or other c++ compilers) installed?
I have successfully installed the ubuntu 18.04.2 version onto my XPS 7590, but the killer wifi card does not work. I researched ahead and knew this would be a problem and found the solution here: https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/. Using this guide, I downloaded the suggested git repositories to a usb, but was disappointed to find that the ISO of ubuntu 18.04.2 did not include an install of make! When I got a GNU of make, I was frustrated when I found out it doesn't even include gcc! As far as I can tell it is extremely difficult to install these modules without internet - which I need the modules to be able to install the drivers to use my internet so... It's been a very frustrating catch 22. I honestly don't understand why such useful modules would not be included in the first place, but maybe that's my naivety.

Comment: Most people complain that Ubuntu is bloated (ie. already includes software that many people don't use), so no the package `build-essential` is not included by default as most don't need it. If you need it, add it (& deps) to your thumb-drive, or add an ethernet cable temporarily to your machine to download that way, then use wifi (*yeah I'm assuming your box has ethernet*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a list of the packages you need to install by running the following command:

```
apt-get --simulate install build-essential 2>&1 | grep "^  [a-z0-9]" | sed 's/^T.*$//g;s/ /\n/g' | tee packages.txt
```

A copy of this list will be in your `~/Downloads` directory if you need it.

---

Then, you can go to a working computer and you can download each package on the list by using the following url (replacing "packagename" with the actual package):

```
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/<packagename>/download
```

Here is an example of the url to download `make`:

```
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/make/download
```

Just click on one of the listed mirrors to download.

**Don't forget to also download `build-essential`!**

---

You will need to copy all of the downloaded packages (as root user) to the following directory:

`/var/cache/apt/archives`

Finally, you can run the following commands to install the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

[SOURCE](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2250428#post_13154723)