# How to install driver for ReakTek rtl8821ce with NO ETHERNET PORT

Tags: networking, drivers

I just bought a new HP 15-ef0875ms laptop and am trying to install Xubuntu 18.04.4. The network card is not recognized.

Steps I have taken:

- I downloaded the driver using other answers here.
- I tried to build the driver. `make` is not installed.
- I tried to install make. I don't have build-essential, gcc, g++, or other installed.
- I tried to install those. Dependency hell ensues. Eventually it tells me I can't install dpkg-dev because of libdpkg-perl version being too new.
- I am lost.

What can I do without any internet access of any kind on the machine itself?

Comment: Connect using USB and your phone. There is a lot of online manuals.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go online on any system having a USB port.

Connect your phone with a USB cable and turn on USB modem mode there.

It is a lot easier for a newbie that to manually install many packages with dependencies.

Comment: This will not work with my phone which does not have the USB tethering option.

Comment: All Android phones and iphones have it. Otherwise you'll need to downloade all packages with proper versions. No other way.

Answer (score -1):

1. Borrow modern phone and use @Pilot6 user's advice
2. Download all required packages using [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1162055/925971):

   ```
   apt-get --simulate install build-essential 2>&1 | grep "^  [a-z0-9]" | sed 's/^T.*$//g;s/ /\n/g' | tee packages.txt
   ```

   Using `packages.txt` file you could make a script to automatically download these packages on system with working network adapter through `wget`.
3. Copying packages from cache on machine with internet:

   - Duplicate installation on PC with network access
   - `sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install make gcc build-essential`
   - `sudo cp /var/cache/apt /your/usbdisk/` on machine with internet
   - `cd /your/usbdisk/apt && sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
4. [Create customized Ubuntu 18.04 distribution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd) enabling required build packages
5. And also, maybe driver could be compiled on the other machine with the same kernel...

Comment: That won't solve the core driver problem if it's not shipped with the kernel already.

Comment: @ThomasWard Recently people were asking about wi-fi stopping working after upgrade. Returning to older kernels helped them. It could be the case with not proper  kernel shipped with OP's distributive he installed.

Comment: rtl8821ce is not present in any current Ubuntu version. Sorry.

Comment: Ok. Deleted that as useless

Comment: @chili555 actually it is in the ubuntu repos. see https://askubuntu.com/a/1251494/1103604